why flutter defaults to android:launchMode="singleTop"?
After a simple flutter create my android launch mode is set to "singleTop".
<!-- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            ...

This is awful user experience. It prevents screen split, multiple instances and maybe other desirable features.
Why is that needed? I changed it back to "standard" and saw no problems from it.
my question is: what? What will break setting it to "standard"?

Maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511492/10650407

@ThangPhi thanks! i went over the official docs which also describe it very well. My point is, the default choice flutter makes is limiting. I want to understand why. It is clearly a hack to work around something.

From curiosity, why do you need multiple instances? That should never occur on Android. Screen split works just fine with Flutter apps, no need to change launch mode.

@user1209216 i don't really. I mean, i would love to, but android is completely broken on that aspect. Some PDF readers try to, but then they get stuck into the gmail/whatsapp activity... it's worse than if they didn't!  what I do care about is screen split.

In an Android native app, an app can deep link into another app by initializing an activity.
However, when launchMode:singleTop is used in the manifest, a new activity is created
when the current activity isn't at the top of the target task. This means that a new Dart
entrypoint is created every time a new activity is created.
Because an activity has a 1:1 relation with a Flutter engine, there's no state synchronization
between these two activities that would allow an app to skip certain screen. e.g. a login screen.

oh, so it is the laziest hack to prevent users from not validating their own application state?! is this really the reason that was discussed at the time this changed? or just a (very good) guess (since they push their cloud login pretty hard with flutter)?
